# WinRT - How to Enable "Timed Logout" Feature in Webview or Detect Pointer Pressed/Tapping Event in Webview

Tags: webview, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am developing a WinRT app. One of the requirements is that the app should have a "timed logout" feature. What this means is that on any screen, if the app has been idle for 10 mins, the app should logout and navigate back to the home screen.

By using this link and applied the logic given in below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18878954/3560390

**Its works fine in all screens except webview,because webview not supports any touch event or tap event.**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx

How to enable "timed logout" feature in WinRT webview ?

Any help is welcome..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this limitation hasn't been fixed with the improvements to the WebView in Windows 10.

Here are 2 things you can try:

1) When the user navigates to the page, begin your 10 minute timer. After 10 minutes, display a modal dialog with an "**OK**" button which says something like "*Click to continue browsing...*". The user then has 10 seconds (or whatever you choose) to click **OK**. If not, then navigate back to the home screen.

2) The WebView does have working `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events. Perhaps you can use these methods to restart your 10 minute timer.

### An Idea

***If*** your WebView is loading content with **ms-appx-web, ms-local-stream,** or **https** content (which would require a content URI rule in your appxmanifest) **OR** if you are using `NavigateToString`, then you may be able to do something like this:

```
private void WebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    MyWebView.InvokeScript("eval", new[]
    {
        "document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(){window.external.notify('MouseMove');});"
    });
}

private void MyWebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    if( e.Value == "MouseMove" )
    {
        // Restart timer
    }
}
```